# User authorization using custom middleware in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have made `VerifyUserAccess` `middleware` in `loopback` as below:

```
module.exports = function(options) {
 return function storeCurrentUser(req, res, next) {
 if (!req.accessToken) {
  return next();
 }

app.models.UserModel.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  if (!user) {
    return next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.'));
  }
  const LoopBackContext = require('loopback-context');
  const loopbackContext = LoopBackContext.getCurrentContext();
  if (loopbackContext) {
    loopbackContext.set('currentUser', user);
  }
  next();
});
};
};
```

And Also I added it in `middleware.json` as below:

```
 ...
  "initial": {
     "./middleware/verify_user_access": {},
  ...
   }
  ...
```

But problem is that always `loopbackContext` I got `null`.

And the second question is that how to access `currentUser` result in `API`. I have done below:

```
  Gameversionandtype.GetGameversionandtypeByGameTypeID = (ctx, callback) => 
 {
    const LoopBackContext = require('loopback-context');
    const context = LoopBackContext.getCurrentContext();
    const currentUserResult = context && context.get('currentUserResult');
    console.log('currentUser.username: ', currentUserResult.id);
    ...
    ...
 }
```

And Please let me know that how to set `currentUser` result and how to get it in `API`. I have referred documentation as well `loopback-context` `npm` module but I can not find any solutions. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Require `LoopBackContext` at the top of your codes.

Comment: But why, we have to declare it top of the code? Can you explain it in detail?